# How can I determine if a jquery click in one section of the page is related to an element?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery event handler:

```
$('html').click(function(event) {
    if ( ! $(".ronstoppable").find($(event.target))){
        if ($('.dropdown').is(':visible')){
            $('.dropdown').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

This checks whether, when I click anywhere on the page, if the actual spot is a child of a particular element, then do *not* do anything.

This is because I have a popup—if the user clicks outside the popup, the popup disappears. If they click in it, well, I don't want the popup to disappear.

However, this code doesn't work—nothing happens when they click in the popup (yay), but similarly and sadly, nothing happens when they click outside of the popup (boo).

How do I fix this so the popup goes away when the users clicks outside of it?

Please don't `stopPropagation()` or anything, I'm using jQuery mobile and it gets **super** upset when anything doesn't propagate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because .find() returns a jQuery object which is truthy all the time... so you if condition will never gets executed...

I think what you can try is to use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to see whether `.ronstoppable` is an ancestor of the target element

```
$('html').click(function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest(".ronstoppable").length) {
        if ($('.dropdown').is(':visible')) {
            $('.dropdown').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are checking for children, you can count them to check if any were found using find():

```
if ( $(".ronstoppable").find($(event.target)).length != 0){
    //your awesome code goes here
} else {
    //boo
}
```

Comment: sigh - this is actually the solution i ended up with overnight. Arun just happened to submit sooner.